# AWS S3 Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-control, accesscontrolexception

Im using [slim image cropper](http://slimimagecropper.com) and Im saving the cropped image to S3, While storing i get Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header..Also i find the issue is not frequent.

> for every "ten" s3 request, i find the error pop up once (this is approx)

my cros setting is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

also i tried adding policy as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

but still could not solve.

I found there is `no header information` from s3 regarding access control. Is there a better way of getting the image with the header.

my bucket policy is

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1483356111760",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1483356411157",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wed2wed2test/*"
    }
]
}
```

exact error message

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/loginPortal?lpru=https%3A%2F%2Fs3-console-us-standard.console.aws.amazon.com%2Fs3%2Fcws%2FTattle%3F&lpa=Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s3-console-us-standard.console.aws.amazon.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: *i find the error pop up once (this is approx)* ...what's the exact error message, and what are the exact headers accompanying a request and response that triggers this error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot..I have added exact error message

Comment: That's an interesting error, because it makes no sense at all.  Why would your script be trying to log in to the AWS console, and have an origin of `https://s3-console-us-standard.console.aws.amazon.com`?